# Finding Lexicographically smallest arrangement of some string

Tags: c++, algorithm, permutation, breadth-first-search

The Title might seem as if it is a very common question but please bear with me.

Basically lets say at each index of the string you know which alphabets could be in that index, and then you want to find lexicographically smallest arrangement.

So for example:

```
Index  |  Options
-------|----------
  1    |  'b'
  2    |  'c', 'a'
  3    |  'd', 'c'
  4    |  'c', 'a'
```

So hence, o/p should be `badc`. And yes btw, characters cannot repeat so no greedy algorithm.

I think we could use some sort of Breadth First Search by creating a queue or something of the string and each time we found we could not create another permutation, you pop that out of the list. Doubt this is optimal though, must be something in `O(N)`. Any ideas?

And no, I don't think C is bad, but I would prefer code snippets in C/C++ :p

Thanks!

Comment: Either that should be "bacd" or I don't understand the question yet.

Comment: What is the maximum size of the string?

Comment: How is the output `badc`, can you explain?

Comment: @ecotax How can it be "bacd", the character 'd' is not an option for index 4.

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2, since chars cannot repeat,length will have to be <=26 else there is no such string.

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad If you choose 'c' for index 3, you can't choose 'c' for index 4, and neither can you choose 'a', which leaves you with no option but to choose 'd' for index 3.

Comment: @user3286661 Thanks, misread + now I see the problem.

Comment: This would be much simpler in Prolog, using backtracking.

Comment: @user3286661 why can't "bcda" be the right answer?

Comment: @nomanpouigt It should be lexicographically smallest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved by matching algorithm. You can use a network flow solution to solve this. This can be broken down into a bi-partite graph problem.

To be precise maximum weight assignment problem or maximum cost maximum matching would be a solution.

Below is the bipartite set of vertices -

```
LEVEL          Alphabets
 1                 a  
 2                 b
 3                 c
 4                 d
                   e
                   .
                   .
                   .
                   z
```

Now assign edges from set Level to set Alphabet, only and only if those are the options for that level. So these will be edges here - {1,b} , {2,a}, {2,c} , {3,c} , {3,d} ,{4,a} ,{4,c}
Now, to get the lexicographically least result you need to assign weight to the edges in this fashion -

```
Edge Wt. = 26^(N-Level) * ('z' - Alphabet)
```

So for example edge weight for edge {2,c} would be

```
26^(4-2) * (26-3) =  26^2*23
```

Now you can use a standard maximum cost maximum matching solution. Which is a polynomial solution. And this would be the best approach as far as I can think now. The naive solution is an exponential solution 26^N, so I think you would be happy with a polynomial solution.

Comment: The string can be as long as 26 characters which make the edge weights very big. Be careful about that.

Comment: I think i'll use this, just going to learn maximum cost maximum matching first. Sort of a noob at the moment :)

Comment: @adisticated: how did you get that formula to assign edge weights?

Answer (score 0):

The naive approach is to use backtracking and try every possible solution, however it won't be efficient enough(26!). Then you can improve this backtrack solution by using dynamic programming with the help of bitmask. A bitmask can help you store which characters you have used so far.

Write a recursive function that takes an two inputs, the index which should assign a character to, and a bitmask which indicates which characters we have used so far. Initially the bitmask contains 26 zeros which means we haven't used any characters. After assigning a character to some index we change the bitmask accordingly. For example if we use character *a* we set the first bit of the bitmask to 1. This way you won't solve a lot of overlapping sub-problems.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

vector<vector<char> > data;
map< pair<int,int>, string > dp;

string func( int index, int bitmask ){
    pair<int,int> p = make_pair(index,bitmask);
    if ( dp.count( p ) )
        return dp[p];
    string min_str = "";
    for ( int i=0; i<data[index].size(); ++i ){
        if ( (bitmask&(1<<(data[index][i]-'a'))) == 0 ){
            string cur_str = "";
            cur_str += data[index][i];
            if ( index+1 != data.size() ){
                int mask = bitmask;
                mask |= 1<<(data[index][i]-'a');
                string sub = func(index+1, mask);
                if (sub == "")
                    continue;    
                cur_str += sub;
            }
            if ( min_str == "" || cur_str < min_str ){
                min_str = cur_str;
            }
        }
    }
    dp[p] = min_str;
    return min_str;
}


int main()
{
    data.resize(4);
    data[0].push_back('b');
    data[1].push_back('c');
    data[1].push_back('a');
    data[2].push_back('d');
    data[2].push_back('c');
    data[3].push_back('c');
    data[3].push_back('a');
    cout << func(0,0) << endl;
}
```

Comment: "however it won't be efficient enough": how do you know ?

Comment: If the problem turns out to be NP-hard, any solution can be efficient.

Comment: knapsack is NP. Do you try to solve it by brute-force or do you use dp?

Comment: A heuristic doesn't improve the worst-case behavior of a problem.

Comment: The problem has limited size with optimal substructure and overlapping sub-problems. This approach worst case is (26)*(2^26). Of course the matching approach is much better.

Comment: What's the cost of the matching approach ?

Comment: The other answer suggest that we should use a Hungarian algorithm which can be implemented in O(n^3)

Comment: If the problem size is bounded, the asymptotic complexities don't help anymore (including NP-hardness).

Comment: Seems interesting, going to look into this solution as well. I just don't know how to implement Bitmasks at the moment. :P

Comment: @AlexStone read this [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bitmasking-and-dynamic-programming-set-1-count-ways-to-assign-unique-cap-to-every-person/) for more information. Also I have provided my implementation in the answer.

Comment: Yeah I saw, thanks! Btw any idea about the complexity of this?

Comment: The worst case is (26)*(2^26). Is this from an online judge or a programming contest? Can you provide a link to the source of the problem?

Comment: Yes this is sort of from a current programming contest. https://www.codechef.com/COWS2016/problems/CVW I found out a way to see which Building Number can be part of which index (there can only be 2 max). Didn't sit down to code it because I know the solution I mentioned in the question would be too slow. I am going to try this question again later because I'm busy with my mid-term exams at the moment. Any ideas though? There might be an easier solution than I think.

Comment: @AlexStone The problem in that link is completely different from what you have asked in this question and has an easier solution. Try to use a greedy algorithm. If you weren't successful ask a new question.